# definition of each section of the scipy linear programming function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

there are a few things which I wish to clarify based on what I have worked on. I know that there is information on the scipy documentation website, but wish to know about them in more detail.

This inquiry is based a question I had earlier asked [Previous question on linear programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824681/solving-multiple-equations-with-many-variables-and-inequality-constraints/39825221#39825221)

**EDIT :** 
**As requested by a viewer**, here is the context of the problem :

```
A_ub = np.array([Calories, Proteins, Carbohydrates, Fats, map(negate, Calories), map(negate, Proteins), map(negate, Carbohydrates), map(negate, Fats)])
b_ub = np.array([468, 33, 17, 30, -346, -25, -12, -22])
c = np.array(map(negate, Calories))
res = linprog(c, A_eq=None, b_eq=None, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, bounds=(0, bare_servings))
print res
```

and I am trying to maximize the equation c^T*x.

I have the following result:

```
  status: 2
  success: False
  fun: 405.0
  x: nan
  message: 'Optimzation failed. Unable to find a feasible starting point.'
  nit: 6
```

the variables in question :

```
Proteins :  [14.99, 4.42, 2.06, 1.42, 0.75, 0.28]
Calories :  [102.38, 178.98, 22.93, 135.57, 93.5, 131.17]
Carbohydrates :  [43.42, 43.42, 32.93, 42.36, 32.93, 32.93]
Fats :  [0.42, 0.94, 0.56, 1.46, 1.5, 0.15]
```

the linear programming function asked is in the above mentioned link

What I want to know is what is `fun`? Is it the maximum value that could be calculated from the to-be-maximized equation by setting up some values of elements of `x` vector (the bounds are `(0,3)`? If so, how can I find this vector? Should I do another linear programming function taking an equality?

**EDIT**:
Furthermore, is there anyway I can get some value above 0 and somewhat close to at least the minimum mentioned in the edit for the equation c^T*x considering the other constraints represented by the Proteins, Fats and Carbohydrates variables

Comment: Could you add the relevant code? Make it an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/). I understand there is a previous question, but it's so much easier if everything is one place, instead of making us go back and forth between pages.

Comment: @Evert : sure, no problem

Comment: ```fun``` is the optimal objective the solver produced, while ```x``` is the vector describing the variable-values which lead to this objective=fun. In your case the solver failed and therefore x is empty/invalid (linprog is very bad compared to other LP-solvers like GLPK, CBC and of course the even better commercial ones like GUROBI, CPLEX...). I don't understand your last question within the edit.

Comment: hey, I wanted to ask if there is any way that I can get the vector x for some value represented by res.fun